# Starterkit with Firebase, readonly

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer-1.0

I was interested in doing a very simple PolymerCLI StarterKit app with Firebase READONLY.  This is my working example.
I answered questions:

1. Best locations for

   Authentication.  All of the examples I looked at start with Authentication, including adding a  tag.  Authentication is not required as long as RULES includes READ:nil.

Please excuse such as simple example, but I had a couple of questions that were not clear.  Happy to get feedback. Will be doing a Starterkit with example authentication screen examples.

**FIREBASE DATA: ( sample data )**

```html
{
  "BIN" : {
    "PF004" : {
      "BINTS01" : 1477921088227,
      "BINTS02" : "2016-10-31 09:38",
      "BinScanWeekNumber" : 45,
      "DriversInitials" : "lt",
      "MissionID" : "lt1477921031516",
      "Q10_FILL_LEVEL" : "01 - 010% -2",
      "Q20_BIN_STATUS" : "300 - ALL GOOD",
      "ValLat" : 27.0026283,
      "ValLong" : -82.1632471,
      "YearNumber" : 2016,
      "recorded" : false
    },
    "PF009" : {
      "BINTS01" : 1477938700818,
      "BINTS02" : "2016-10-31 14:31",
      "BinScanWeekNumber" : 45,
      "DriversInitials" : "lt",
      "MissionID" : "lt1477935967751",
      "Q10_FILL_LEVEL" : "09 - 090% -5",
      "Q20_BIN_STATUS" : "300 - ALL GOOD",
      "ValLat" : 27.4861796,
      "ValLong" : -82.4469888,
      "YearNumber" : 2016,
      "recorded" : false
    },
    "PF011" : {
      "BINTS01" : 1475525655142,
      "BINTS02" : "2016-10-03 16:14",
      "BinScanWeekNumber" : 41,
      "DriversInitials" : "lt",
      "MissionID" : "lt1475525025421",
      "Q10_FILL_LEVEL" : "01 - 010% -2",
      "Q20_BIN_STATUS" : "300 - ALL GOOD",
      "ValLat" : 27.5332609,
      "ValLong" : -82.5033191,
      "YearNumber" : 2016,
      "recorded" : false
    },
```

**RULES:**
Observe that .read:true.

```html
    {
      "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
```

**CODE:  Started with Polymer Starterkit**

---

**index.html**

Stock...  nothing changes.  But probably could do

**my-app.html**
Added polymerfire Elements here. including:

```html
<!-- ***************      FIREBASE ITEMS HERE-->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-query.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-document.html">
<!--<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-auth.html">-->

Also added <firebase-app>
```

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<!-- ***************     ADD FIREBASE ITEMS HERE-->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-app.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-query.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-document.html">
<!--<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymerfire/firebase-auth.html">-->


<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer/app-drawer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-drawer-layout/app-drawer-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header/app-header.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-header-layout/app-header-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-scroll-effects/app-scroll-effects.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-layout/app-toolbar/app-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-route.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-icons.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --app-primary-color: #4285f4;
        --app-secondary-color: black;

        display: block;
      }

      app-header {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: var(--app-primary-color);
      }
      app-header paper-icon-button {
        --paper-icon-button-ink-color: white;
      }

      .drawer-list {
        margin: 0 20px;
      }

      .drawer-list a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: var(--app-secondary-color);
        line-height: 40px;
      }

      .drawer-list a.iron-selected {
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>

 <!--vy adding FIREBASE here-->
<!--Connection to Firebase-->
    <firebase-app
        name="SHOE33"
        api-key="Put API KEY HERE"        
        auth-domain=" shoe33-672de.firebaseapp.com"
        database-url="https://shoe33-672de.firebaseio.com">
    </firebase-app>


    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <app-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/:page"
        data="{{routeData}}"
        tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

    <app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
      <!-- Drawer content -->
      <app-drawer id="drawer">
        <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
        <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
          <a name="view1" href="/view1">View One</a>
          <a name="view2" href="/view2">View Two</a>
          <a name="view3" href="/view3">3 - BIN LIST</a>
          <a name="view4" href="/view4">4 - SCANS</a>
          <a name="view5" href="/view5">5 - MISSIONS</a>
          <a name="view6" href="/view6">View 6</a>
          <a name="view7" href="/view7">View 7</a>
          <a name="view8" href="/view8">View 8</a>
          <a name="view9" href="/view9">View 9</a>                    
        </iron-selector>
      </app-drawer>

      <!-- Main content -->
      <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

        <app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button icon="my-icons:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
            <div main-title>My App</div>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>

        <iron-pages
            selected="[[page]]"
            attr-for-selected="name"
            fallback-selection="view404"
            role="main">
          <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
          <my-view2 name="view2"></my-view2>
          <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
          <my-view4 name="view4"></my-view4>
          <my-view5 name="view5"></my-view5>
          <my-view6 name="view6"></my-view6>
          <my-view7 name="view7"></my-view7>
          <my-view8 name="view8"></my-view8>
          <my-view9 name="view9"></my-view9>                    
          <my-view404 name="view404"></my-view404>
        </iron-pages>
      </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-app',

      properties: {
        page: {
          type: String,
          reflectToAttribute: true,
          observer: '_pageChanged',
        },
      },

      observers: [
        '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)',
      ],

      _routePageChanged: function(page) {
        this.page = page || 'view1';

        if (!this.$.drawer.persistent) {
          this.$.drawer.close();
        }
      },

      _pageChanged: function(page) {
        // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
        var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('my-' + page + '.html');
        this.importHref(resolvedPageUrl, null, this._showPage404, true);
      },

      _showPage404: function() {
        this.page = 'view404';
      },
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**my-view2.html**
Observe:
Using $key]] which refers to the Document root name.

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-view2">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>


    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">2</div>
      <h1>View Two</h1>
      <p>SHOE 01.</p>
      <p>Will attempt to read Shoe Data</p>
      <p>Added the Firebase-auth tag</p>
      <p>Screwing with dom-repeat</p>
      <!--<p>Will attempt to read Shoe Data</p>
      <p>Will attempt to read Shoe Data</p>
      <p>Will attempt to read Shoe Data</p>
      <p>Will attempt to read Shoe Data</p>
      <p>Will attempt to read Shoe Data</p>
      <p>Will attempt to read Shoe Data</p>                        -->
    </div>

<!--Start adding things Polyfire here-->
    <firebase-query
        id="query"
        log
        app-name="SHOE33"
        path="/BIN"
        data="{{bindata}}">
    </firebase-query>


    <!--<firebase-document
        app-name="SHOE33"
        path="/bin"
        data="{{bindata}}">
    </firebase-document>-->


    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">Bin</div>
      <h1>Count of Bins</h1>
      <p> [[bindata.length]] .length  </p>
      <p> [[bindata.BINTS01]] .BINTS01 </p>

    </div>


    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">Bin2</div>
      <h1>Bin List</h1>
      <p>SHOE 01. BIN data</p>

      <p>Put data here....  </p>
      <p> [[bindata.length]] .length  </p>
      <p> [[bindata.BINTS01]] .BINTS01 </p>

    
    </div>
               <p>ccc</p>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[bindata]]" as="bin">
                <p>ccc</p>
                <div class="card-content"> length = [[bin.length]] </div>
                <span>[[bin]]</span>
                <paper-card heading="[[bin]]">
                  <div class="card-content">BIN1 = [[bin.$key]] </div>
                  <div class="card-content">BIN2 = [[bin.id]] </div>
                  <div class="card-content">BIN3 = [[bin.child_added]] </div>  
                  <div class="card-content">BIN4 = [[bin.name]] </div>
                  <div class="card-content">BIN5 = [[bin.child]] </div>                                   
                  <div class="card-content">BIN6 = [[bin.Child]] </div>
                  <div class="card-content">BINTS01 = [[bin.BINTS01]] </div>
                </paper-card>
        </template>


  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-view2',
      properties: {
        uid: String,
        branddata: {
          type: Object,
          observer: 'dataChanged'
        }
      },
      dataChanged: function (newData, oldData) {
        // do something when the query returns values
          console.log("NewData: " + newData);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

If this looks like extremely basic Polymer / Firebase...  it is. But I just wanted to document it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html I see you have a `firebase-app` element but you haven't imported `firebase-app`. Could that be the problem?

Also I see that the name of your `firebasee-app` element doesn't match the name in your `firebase-document` in `my-view2`. Also I don't see an import for `firebase-document` there either.

Also the api key is clearly invalid but I assume you just replaced that for the question - don't think you need to do that, in a published app it would be public anyway.

I'm surprised checking the javascript console in your browser didn't highlight the missing imports. Maybe doing a `polymer build` would have picked it up too. Personally I write unit tests and that usually picks things up pretty quickly

Comment: I made the changes...   you were correct, but still having issues.

Comment: did you update the code snippets above they still look really quite wrong.

- firebase-app needs to be imported in index.html (put it just before the my-app import)
- firebase-auth is not required at all I don't think (you're not authenticating)
- firebase-query needs to be imported in my-view2.html (not firebase-auth or firebase-document, you're not using them)
- the app-name in the firebase-query element needs to match the app-name in the firebase-app element

Comment: you should do this tutorial on polymer-fire, it will take you through what needs configuring and where.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-firebase-pwa/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Answer (score 0):

Which ever file you define the firebase-app element you have to also import every firebase element you want to use even if you are not using it in that file. So from the source above you need to be importing firebase-app and firebase-query in the my-app.html file. Also you are defining the firebase-app in both the index.html as well as the my-app.html, it only needs to be in the my-app.html file.

Comment: Whereas you can import all components there, I'm pretty sure you don't have to and best practice would be to import them everywhere they are used and not where they are not used. That way they can be efficiently loaded only when they are needed (and will not be loaded more than once even if they are imported in multiple files). Plus he is using firebase-app in index.html so it at least has to be imported there and it won't help to import it in my-app.html (although I would probably move the firebase-app element to my-app)

Comment: With the firebase elements specifically in the file where you define the firebase-app element you have import all firebase elements that you plan to use throughout your application as it will only build the parts of the firebase-app data for the elements you import. So to use the firebase-query you have import it both in the file where you define the firebase-app element as well as in the file where you actually use the firebase-query element.